# Cannot connect to local SQL server through socket, using PopSQL in MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, popsql

I am new to SQL.

I can log into the terminal and create databases.

When I opened PopSQL and tried to connect to localhost, an error message appeared:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried many solutions on Internet but they did not work.

Comment: This error could be because of many reasons. Can you also add information about how you installed your local MySQL server? Was it using brew?

Comment: I just downloaded a community server and added that to bash_profile.